# does sql statement ensure atomicity in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, knex.js, acid

I have a simple bug in my program that uses multi user support. I'm using `knex` to build sql queries, and I have a pseudocode that depicts the scenerio:

```
const value = queryBuilder().readDataFromTheDatabase();//executes this
//do some other work and get value
queryBuilder.writeValueToTheDatabase(updateValue(value));
```

This piece of code is being use in sort of a middleware function. And as you can see, this is a possible **race condition** i.e. when multiple users access the thing, one of them gets a stale value when they try to execute this at roughly the same amount of time.

**My solution**

So, I was think a possible solution would be create a single queryBuilder statement:

```
queryBuilder().readAndUpdateValueInTheDatabase();
```

So, I'll probably have to use a little bit of `plpgsql`. I was wondering if this solution will be sufficient. Will the statement be executed atomically? i.e. When one request reads and doesn't finish his write, does another request wait around to both read and write or just waits to write but, reads the stale value?

Comment: You need to decide what variant you want to implement. Either variant is possible. (1) Blocking. As soon as the first client reads a row, the second will wait and start reading that row only after the first client finished writing and released the lock. You need to implement the retry logic if the wait is too long. (2) Optimistic. Many clients are allowed to read the same row without locking. When a client writes, it checks that nobody has changed the row in the meantime and implements the logic to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a race condition with such a setup, you must run both the read and the write in the same database transaction.

There are two ways to do that:

1. Use the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level and lock the rows when you read them:

   ```
   SELECT ... FROM ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE;
   ```

   That locks the rows against concurrent modifications, and the lock is held until the end of the transaction.
2. Use the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level and don't lock anything. Then your `UPDATE` will receive a serialization error (SQLSTATE 40001) if somebody modified the row concurrently. In that case, you roll the transaction back and try again in a new `REPEATABLE READ` transaction.

The first solution is usually better if you expect conflicts frequently, while the second is better if conflicts are rare.

Note that you should keep the database transaction as short as possible in both cases to keep the risk of conflicts low.

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer, I'll read up more about this and get back to this answer in a short while. I think the first solution is better, but, do you think if say 10,000 different transactions come at a single amount of time, and the lock is being held by a single transaction, then, is there a problem such as postgres' buffer being full or something(I'm not sure, but, do they get any kind of buffer allocation to stay during locking?)

Comment: You don't have to worry about buffer overruns. If you have 10000 concurrent transactions, you have other problems (system overload) and need a transaction pool.

Comment: that's true, my curiosity was being spawned from a theoretical perspective.

Comment: I read about isolation level, it seems this is set per transaction using `BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ` , is there a command to enabling this for every transaction?

Comment: You can change the default isolation level with the parameter `default_transaction_isolation`.

Comment: after I use the first solution, and I start to update the rows from multiple threads, it gives me a `rows concurrently updated` problem. Why is this happening? Shouldn't postgres handle the concurrency now?

Comment: No; that is to be expected with `REPEATABLE READ`, it is the serialization error I mentioned in my answer. It means that you have to repeat the transaction. The database doesn't do that for you. That's how optimistic locking works.

Comment: it also appears we can't make functions concurrently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333536/why-postgres-gives-concurrently-row-updated-error-when-im-locking-the-whole-tab/68334374#68334374

Comment: The link is completely unrelated, and you can use a function or not, as you like. The point is that you have to expect a serialization error and repeat the transaction if you get one.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for here is isolation, not atomicity.  You could set all transactions to the highest isolation level, serializable (which is higher than the usual default level).  With that level, if data that a transaction read (and presumably relied upon) is changed, then when it tries to commit it might get a serialization failure error.  I say "might", because the system could conclude the situation would be consistent with the data change having happened after the commit, in which case the commit is allowed to stand.

Comment: would raising isolation level prevent this __racing__ condition as I have portrayed?. I mean, read a value is a single transaction in itself. How would postgres know if a read is being related to a write in the future since the two statements are executed independently?

Comment: and would raising an isolation level make performance issues? Once set, would all transactions in the query in your entire database run with the same isolation level?

Comment: also, on serialization failure, does it attemp to redo the transaction or just cancel it?

Comment: If you read in a different transaction than you use the info that you read, then you are doing it wrong.  Yes, it will have a performance impact.  It will not retry because it doesn't know what decision you would make after looking at the new data.  If the decision is made in the client, only the client can revise/repeat it.

Comment: I'm quoting above: "If you read in a different transaction than you use the info that you read, then you are doing it wrong"..... what would be the right way to do it?    Would making this a same transaction be a good way? And would using a raw query knex statement doing some plpgsql do the trick?    Would that also mean raising `isolation` level also not a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Transaction in PostgreSQL use an optimistic locking model when accessing to tables, while some other DBMS do pessimistic locking (IBM Db2) or the two locking model (MS SQL Server).

Optimistic locking snapshot the data on which you are working, and the modifications are done on the snapshot until the transaction ended. When the transaction finishes, the snapshot modifications are postponed on the real database (table rows), but if some other user had made a change between the moment of the snapshot capture and the commit, then the commit cannot apply and the COMMIT is rejected as a ROLLBACK.

You can try to raise the ISOLATION LEVEL (REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE) to avoid the trouble.

Comment: but, if the COMMIT is rejected as a ROLLBACK doesn't that mean the stale value is not read? And does that also mean both read/write is cancelled or it'll start all over again?

Comment: There is nothing "postponed" when the transaction finishes. The committed changes are immediately available.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ,  Would making this a same transaction be a good way? And would using a raw query knex statement doing some plpgsql do the trick? Would that also mean raising isolation level also not a solution to the problem?

Comment: Almost everything about this answer is wrong, sorry.